# How to replace Rspec's ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test' deprecated in Rails 3.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, rspec-rails

I'm using `rails (3.0.4)` and `rspec-rails (2.5.0). When I run`rails generate rspec:install
`it produces`spec_helper.rb` that contains this line:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
```

When I run `rake spec` I get this warning on in the terminal:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: RAILS_ENV is deprecated. Please use ::Rails.env.
```

This isn't as annoying since that only runs once inside my `Spork.prefork`, but I'd like to get past that deprecation if possible. I'm new to Rails and haven't found mention of this in the [rspec-rails issues](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues) or anywhere else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dup of my response in the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/328):

That warning is telling you that the constant `RAILS_ENV` is deprecated, not the environment variable `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]`. If you clone the Rails repo and check out the v3.0.4 tag, and search for `RAILS_ENV`, you'll see that Rails, itself, uses `ENV["RAILS_ENV"]` in several places.

Must be coming from somewhere else in your app.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was with the newrelic_rpm gem.

Answer (score 2):

Must be new in Rails 3.0.4. This ought to work:

Remove the `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || = 'test'` from spec/spec_helper.rb

Look for the `require rspec/rails` line.

Add `::Rails.env ||= 'test'` immediately after it.

It would be a good idea to open an issue on the rspec-rails tracker, as this is going to need changing.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. [Issue reported](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/328).

Comment: Update, that doesn't work. Rails.env returns `development` at that point, so the `||=` does nothing. It took me a while to figure out why my tests were running on my development db. :)